# How to create a screen of 1/3 width on top of another screen of full width in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, screen

Onclick of a Filter icon in the appbar,  I should display a Filter screen of 1/3 width on top of the current screen of full width.. May I know how to do this in Flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possibilities:

1. Use a Drawer
   https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer

This is designed to do exactly what you want. Works with Scaffolds

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool showOverlay = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("app bar")),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Test"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. Overlay Entry
   https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverlayEntry-class.html

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  OverlayEntry? overlay;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("app bar")),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            final _overlay = _createOverlayEntry(context);
            Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_overlay);
            setState(() {
              overlay = _overlay;
            });
          },
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Test"),
        ));
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * (1.0 / 3.0),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
   top: 0,
        left: 0,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("close"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // close overlay
                    overlay?.remove();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

3. Simple Stack
   https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

   ```html
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   void main() {
     runApp(MaterialApp(
       home: MyApp(),
     ));
   }

   class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
   }

   class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
     bool showOverlay = false;
     @override
     void initState() {
       super.initState();
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Stack(
         children: [
           Scaffold(
             appBar: AppBar(title: Text("app bar")),
             floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
               child: Icon(Icons.add),
               onPressed: () {
                 setState(() {
                   showOverlay = true;
                 });
               },
             ),
             body: Center(
               child: Text("Test"),
             ),
           ),
           if (showOverlay)
             Positioned(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * (1.0 / 3.0),
           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      top: 0,
           left: 0,
               child: Container(
                 color: Colors.red,
                 child: Center(
                   child: ElevatedButton(
                     child: Text("close"),
                     onPressed: () {
                       setState(() {
                         showOverlay = false;
                       });
                     },
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
         ],
       );
     }
   }
   ```